# Using email as username field in Django 1.5 custom User model results in FieldError

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.5

I want to use an email field as the username field for my custom user model.
I have the following custom User model subclassing Django's AbstractUser model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ....
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

But when I run

> python manage.py sql myapp

I get the following error:

> FieldError: Local field 'email' in class 'CustomUser' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'

The reason I include my own email field in the first place is to add the `unique=True` option to it. otherwise I get:

> myapp.customuser: The USERNAME_FIELD must be unique. Add unique=True to the field parameters.

Now, in respect to this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted
How **can** I achieve this? (other then naming the field "user_email" or something like that instead)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ian, thank you very much for the clever response :)

However, I've already "patched" me a solution.

Since `AbstractUser` also have a `username` field which is totaly unnecessary for me
I decided to create my "own" `AbstractUser`.

By subclassing `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin` I retain most of the User model built-in methods without adding any code.

I also took advantage of that opportunity to create a custom `Manager` to eliminate the use in  `username` field all together:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     ....
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
     first_name = ...
     last_name = ...
     is_active = ...
     is_staff = ...
     ....

     objects = CustomUserManager()

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
     def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
          .....

     def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
          .....
```

This solution does result in repetition of some of Django's built-in code (mainly model fields that already exist in `AbstractUser` such as 'first_name', 'last_name' etc.) but also in a cleaner User object and database table.

It is a real shame that the flexibily introduced in 1.5 with `USERNAME_FIELD` can not be used to **actualy** create a flexible User model under all existing constrains.

EDIT: There is a comprehensive worked example available in the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: What does your create_superuser method contain?

Comment: It creates a user object with no `username` field (with `email` instead) using create_user: `u = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)`, sets the superuser "special" fields (`is_staff, is_superuser, ...`) and then saves that user.

Comment: is implementation of `CustomUserMananger` a must have or can I skip it and deafault django's staff will be aplied?

Comment: @andi From what I saw back then, the `username` argument was mandatory for `create_superuser` under Django's `UserManager`. Because I removed the `username` field from my user model, this gave me an error when I was trying to create a superuser through the Linux shell using Django's builtin "project creation" procces (which uses Django's `createsuperuser` script, which in turn uses `create_superuser` method from your `CustomUser` model manager).
Overrinding and defining `create_superuser` without `username` solved the problem.

Comment: As I couldn't insert the link in my previous comment (the comment was "too long"), here's Django's own [`UserManager`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a9093dd3763df6b2045a08b0520f248bda708723/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L162)

Answer (score 12):

If your real target is unique "email" values, and ignoring "username" values, then you may:

- Fill "username" with e.g. `sha256(user.email).hexdigest()[:30]`
- Add uniqueness this way:

  ```
  class User(AbstractUser):
      class Meta:
          unique_together = ('email', )
  ```

This results in:

```
CREATE TABLE "myapp_user" (
    ...
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("email")
)
```

works just as expected, and is pretty simple.

Comment: This was the best option that I have seen when dealing with this matter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you put the code to fill username?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there are many ways, e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#creating-users

Comment: @DenisRyzhkov That is good when I create user in my code, but it's the backend, e.g. `allauth` that creates users. So, I need to somehow instrument it...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning try either https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Answer (score 9):

You can edit your `CustomUser` to change the `email` field attribute to `unique=True`.

Add this to the end of your custom user class like so:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    ...
CustomUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True
```

Note that we're changing `_unique` and not `unique` because the latter is a simple `@property`.

This is a hack, and I would love to hear any "official" answers to resolve this.

Comment: I had to use `CustomUser._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True`

Answer (score 2):

Use the example from the official site :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

> Here is an example of an admin-compliant custom user app. This user model uses an email address as the username, and has a required date of birth; it provides no permission checking, beyond a simple admin flag on the user account. This model would be compatible with all the built-in auth forms and views, except for the User creation forms. This example illustrates how most of the components work together, but is not intended to be copied directly into projects for production use.

Comment: This is actually the way to go

Comment: Is all this really necessary just to change the USERNAME_FIELD?