# Can I change the USERNAME_FIELD in Django 1.5 without creating a custom user?

Tags: django, email, model, django-1.5

I am trying to use the email field in the default Django user model as the username. I am using Django 1.5 and I saw that the default user has a `USERNAME_FIELD` property.

In my project, I would like to set the following `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` as a default in the user model.

This small but fundamental tweak is the only thing I would like to change in the user model. I was wondering if there is a way of changing the `USERNAME_FIELD` without having to subclass the `AbstractUser`. I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597188/) that you can subclass the `AbstractUser` and write a custom manager for it.

So I was wondering if there is a simpler way of changing that property?

And if not, what would be the minimal way of extending the `AbstractUser` to use the email field as username?

Comment: use AbstraceBaseUser instead

Comment: @catherine If you Subclass AbstractUser you end up in these problems:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605453/django-1-5-extend-the-default-user-model-or-substitute-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601412/upgrading-django-to-1-5-with-django-cms-user-model-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#Your app's __init__.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User.USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: This raises the error "django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
auth.user: The field named as the USERNAME_FIELD should not be included in REQUIRED_FIELDS on a swappable User model.
auth.user: The USERNAME_FIELD must be unique. Add unique=True to the field parameters." for me.

Comment: Same problem with me... I wonder if there have been any changes that break this between Mar '13 and May '13 or so. I would have really liked for this to work..

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a new Custom User Class by extending the AbstractBaseUser and not AbstractUser

Declare your email as the USERNAME_FIELD there

Optionally you can also declare a custom user manager that extends from BaseUserManager to handle the username required constraint. 
You can remove username from that manager's create_user function