# Django 1.6 AbstractUser not working

Tags: django

Trying to create my custom user model, this is the code I have:

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

CustomUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

When doing the manage.py syncdb, the following error occurs:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
myapp.customuser: The field named as the USERNAME_FIELD should not be included in REQUIRED_FIELDS on a swappable User model.
```

Can anyone shed some light? Is there a better way of customizing the user model in Django 1.6 without rewriting the entire class extending AbstractBaseUser?

Btw, if I delete USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' from my code and change the core django auth/models.py >> AbstractUser definition, it works. I just can't seem to be able to override the USERNAME_FIELD...

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

As made clear by the error message, the reason for is that `AbstractUser` defines `REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']`. And you cannot set a field in the `REQUIRED_FIELDS` to be your `USERNAME_FIELD`. Further detail [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20097).

So if you want `email` as your primary field the way forward is to extend and redefine the field `email` on `AbstractBaseUser` rather than on `AbstractUser`.

Also this [question/answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668124/can-i-change-the-username-field-in-django-1-5-without-creating-a-custom-user) might be relevant to you in case I did not fully grasp your requirements.

Answer (score 7):

Josvic, your solution partially resolved my issue. What I had to do in the end was this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email

CustomUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True
```

This resolved the initial issue that REQUIRED_FIELDS cannot contain the USERNAME_FIELD and as I do not want to redefine the entire User and extend the AbstractBaseUser, I had to include the 'username' in the REQUIRED_FIELD as otherwise the syncdb fails for a different reason (expecting the username for the sake of saving it into the db):

```
self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Consequently, when doing the syncdb for the first time and having to enter a superuser, the email must be entered twice, as an email as well as a username. It's awkward but it's the cleanest one that I can live with it.

Cheers!

Comment: Not sure about "cleanest" as you're setting a default in a parent class that I doubt is meant to be set in subclasses; I'm referring to `REQUIRED_FIELDS` property. Try to make this fact explicit in your codebase. I would simply inherit from a class higher in the hierarchy, even if that implies the implementation fields that `AbstractUser` already provides.

Comment: @rok in newer versions of Django the row
`CustomUser._meta.get_field_by_name('email')[0]._unique=True`
should be replaced with:
`CustomUser._meta.get_field('email')._unique=True`

Answer (score 2):

Josvic hit the nail on the head but I want to provide the solution I used. It's pretty simple.

1. Remove 'email' or whatever you're using are `USERNAME_FIELD` from `REQUIRE_FIELDS`.
2. In the UserManager that you made, simply write:

   if not email:
       raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

This way, you'll manually enforce that an email is required.

This solution is the one that is used here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example