# how to change USERNAME_FIELD in Django 3.0.8. without creating a custom user?

Tags: django

i know [same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668124/can-i-change-the-username-field-in-django-1-5-without-creating-a-custom-user) has already been asked and tried that solution by putting
`User.USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`
in `__init__.py` file but it gives error

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'account',
]
```

Comment: i have only two apps maiapp and account and tried putting in both app's __init__.py

Comment: can you add the value of `INSTALLED_APPS`?