# Can't create superuser in Django using custom user

Tags: python, django

I got this error when i try to run manage.py createsuperuser

> TypeError: UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

My User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=140,  unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

and in my settings.py file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usuarios.User'
```

How can i solve this? Im new in Django, documentation is confused to me...

I already tried remove AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usuarios.User' or remove username attribute from class User

Comment: you have to define a user manager class that has two methods, `create_user`, and `create_superuser`

Comment: Remove username field form model manager

Comment: This should help you [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597188/using-email-as-username-field-in-django-1-5-custom-user-model-results-in-fielder?rq=1). It relates to what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create superuser with custom user model like above you have to implement
the method **create_superuser** in the custom UserManager class some thing like bellow.and you need to specify **username field** in custom user model like bellow. Then specify the custom user model in the settings

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
   mobile = models.CharField("Mobile No",max_length=10,unique=True)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   
   objects = CustUserManager()     # custom object manager
   USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobile'   # custom username field (**in this case mobile**)

 class CustUserManager(BaseUserManager):

   def create_superuser(self,mobile,password=None,**extra_fields):
     user = self.create_user(mobile,password)
     user.is_superuser = True
     user.save(using=self._db)
   def create_user(self,email,account_no,password=None,**extra_fields):
      #code to create user like above
```